# How can I stop the Nav Bar from overlapping my content if it follows the margin that I set on the body?

Tags: css, html, css-position

When I try adding margin to displace the content that is hidden under the Nav Bar, the bar moves with the body even though it is fixed.

I researched a bit and other answers provide the same response to what I've tried such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250261/html-positioning-overlap-between-navigation-bar-and-text)

I have tried plenty of things, mostly messing with margins and padding in the body and navbar but nothing seems to work as i'd like.

Here is the CSS and HTML:

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #FFF1CF;
}
li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #000;
}
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  min-width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #FFF1CF;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
}
.ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.txt {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #3399FF;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 640px;
}
#textdiv {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.sideborder1 {
  height: 600px;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
}
.sideborder2 {
  height: 600px;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
}
.centerimg {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 30%;
}
.dropdiv {
  padding-top: 10%;
}
.font1
/*Regular Text*/

{
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
.font2
/*Title*/

{
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #FFF1CF;
}
#font3
/*SubTitle*/

{
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', cursive;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.tryingtowork {
  /*background-image: url("RBS.png");
background-position:0% 40%;*/
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tryingtowork2 {
  background-color: #AAA;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tryingtowork3 {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tryingtowork4 {
  background-color: #BBB;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.blogpost {
  background-color: #CCC;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #FFF
}
#blogcontainer {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: FFF;
  border: 5px solid #FFF
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<header>
  <title>RBS - Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="RBS.ico">
</header>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li style="padding-right:20%;padding-left:2.5%;letter-spacing:.3em;">
        <a class="font2" href="index.html">RBS</a>
      </li>
      <li id="font3" class="dropdown">
        <a href="games.html" class="dropbtn">Games</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#Evolution">Game?</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="font3" class="dropdown">
        <a href="community.html" class="dropbtn">Community</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="Blog.html">Blog</a>
          <a href="#Facebook">Facebook</a>
          <a href="#Twitter">Twitter</a>
          <a href="#Reddit">Reddit</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="font3">
        <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section class="tryingtowork">
    <p class="font1">
      Hello (Info Goes Here)
      <br>This is our community page
      <br>Here is where we can display news and other things:
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>And here is other stuff
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="tryingtowork2">
    <p class="font1">
      ShowCase Goes Here
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="tryingtowork3">
    <p class="font1">
      News Goes Here
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="tryingtowork4">
    <p class="font1">
      Social Media Goes Here
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>B
    </p>
  </section </body>

  </html>
```

and here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/823r43gm/)

**EDIT:**

Thank you all! I didn't realize I had two ULs, one a class and the other just affecting all UL so my top:0 was never being read. This helped lots!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add padding on `body` `30px` & apply `top:0` on navigation ul

```
body {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 30px 0 0;
}
ul {
    background-color: green;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/823r43gm/1/

Comment: He already has top:0 on the nav ul, its just further down the css.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I had two Uls, one a class and the other just affecting all ul so my top:0 was never being read. This helped lots!

Answer (score 1):

So I made two changes to your code:

1. Added `top: 0` to the `ul` in the `nav` element.
2. Added some margin to the topmost section- used `calc` to adjust it:

   ```
   .tryingtowork {
     /*background-image: url("RBS.png");
     background-position:0% 40%;*/
     width: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     margin-top: calc(40px + 1.2em);
   }
   ```

And that's it. Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #FFF1CF;
}
li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #000;
}
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  min-width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #FFF1CF;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
}
.ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.txt {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #3399FF;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 640px;
}
#textdiv {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.sideborder1 {
  height: 600px;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
}
.sideborder2 {
  height: 600px;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
}
.centerimg {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 30%;
}
.dropdiv {
  padding-top: 10%;
}
.font1
/*Regular Text*/

{
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
.font2
/*Title*/

{
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #FFF1CF;
}
#font3
/*SubTitle*/

{
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', cursive;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.tryingtowork {
  /*background-image: url("RBS.png");
background-position:0% 40%;*/
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: calc(40px + 1.2em);
}
.tryingtowork2 {
  background-color: #AAA;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tryingtowork3 {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tryingtowork4 {
  background-color: #BBB;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.blogpost {
  background-color: #CCC;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #FFF
}
#blogcontainer {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: FFF;
  border: 5px solid #FFF
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<header>
  <title>RBS - Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="RBS.ico">
</header>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li style="padding-right:20%;padding-left:2.5%;letter-spacing:.3em;">
        <a class="font2" href="index.html">RBS</a>
      </li>
      <li id="font3" class="dropdown">
        <a href="games.html" class="dropbtn">Games</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#Evolution">Game?</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="font3" class="dropdown">
        <a href="community.html" class="dropbtn">Community</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="Blog.html">Blog</a>
          <a href="#Facebook">Facebook</a>
          <a href="#Twitter">Twitter</a>
          <a href="#Reddit">Reddit</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="font3">
        <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section class="tryingtowork">
    <p class="font1">
      Hello (Info Goes Here)
      <br>This is our community page
      <br>Here is where we can display news and other things:
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>And here is other stuff
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="tryingtowork2">
    <p class="font1">
      ShowCase Goes Here
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="tryingtowork3">
    <p class="font1">
      News Goes Here
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="tryingtowork4">
    <p class="font1">
      Social Media Goes Here
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>B
    </p>
  </section </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the margin calculation adjustment idea! I believe it will serve me well, I didn't know that was possible. I'm only new at CSS :)

Comment: I did, although it doesn't seem to count publicly due to my reputation. Odd

Comment: ohh I see... I think you need 15 reps to do that... :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move your `position:fixed;` from the `<ul>` element to the `<nav>` element and also add `width:100%;`

Then you can add padding to your content to stop it from being overlapped by the nav bar.

I have updated your JSfiddle with the changes here: https://jsfiddle.net/michaelsherry/823r43gm/2/

CSS should be:

```
nav {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: green;
    width:100%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would fix the `<nav>`not the `<ul>`, and put a margin on the first block of content.

```
nav{position:fixed; top:0; left:0;}

.tryingtowork { margin-top: 30px;}
```

[Updated JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/823r43gm/3/)